# What is a presentation of the upper triangular subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb Q)$?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I have been trying to find a presentation of the upper triangular subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb Q)$ by considering the free group $Fr(\{x_i| i\in \mathbb Q\})$ under a homomorphism $f$ into $GL(2, \mathbb Q)$ by

$f(x_i):=\begin{bmatrix}i&b\\&{1\over i}\end{bmatrix}$ or $f(x_i):=\begin{bmatrix}i&b\\& {i^2} \end{bmatrix}$ but I haven't been able to finagle it enough to get it to work. Is this at all the right approach? How exactly do I go about finding a presentation in the proper way? Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I would probably go with generators of the form $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks. I guess I was just approaching the problem wrongly. When is is that I should be looking to establish isomorphisms from the quotient of the free group with the kernel of some homomorphism like I was above, as compared to just trying stuff with generators?

Comment: Well, for example, you could write a "normal form" representation such as $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & c^{-1} b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}$ and then come up with enough relations to be able to write a product of two such expressions in the same form, and possibly some relations for inverses as well.

Comment: Otherwise, "send" $\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}, a \in \mathbb{Q}^*, b \in \mathbb{Q}^*,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ to the element $x_{a,b,c}$ of the free group generated by the elements of $\mathbb{Q}^*\times \mathbb{Q}^* \times \mathbb{Q}$, then define the  multiplication in term of elements of that free group.